# Crazy about this robot arm rig

Tags: rigging

as a beginner in Blender I am currently struggling with rigging and bone constraints.... actually I am not sure if I am just doing something wrong or missing something essentially, maybe someone can give me a hint in the right direction...

I am trying to rig an industrial robot arm, the basic rig works but not exactly the way I want to... when moving the target away from the root, the last part of the robot arm starts to rotate slightly whereas I want the bone with the arrow to always point straight down, while still keeping my target bone on the tip of the thing that is attached to the arm's end... locking the x,y,z under the bone's IK tab doesn't do anything, locking all the rotation axes under the transform tab neither....

[image]

It's probably super simple but after a whole day of trying to figure out the problem I would greatly appreciate any kind of help ;-)

Well, well... I made some progress on the downwards directed bone by parenting an empty on one of the bone's end, then parenting another empty below that with a copy location constraint disregarding the z axis.... so the green bone now always points to the empty below - my only problem is that my ik chain is now controlled by the orange bone, while I would still love to control the whole ik chain with my little target bone at the end (this will be where I need my target to be) - would this require a second ik chain or am I completely going the wrong path? :/

[image]

Comment: Please add images directly into your question rather than making folks go to an external site which may not exist in future to view them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Also please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: There are two different methods for "IK Chains", one uses the IK Bone constraint, while a similar technique is achieved with a Stretch_To constraint.  Which bone do you have an IK constraint applied: the orange or the bone right near the IK end-bone?  Add a screen-cap of the IK constraint so we can see Chain Length.   As moonboots suggests, include your blend file as many helpful people will jump at the chance of to gain "reputation points" by helping you.